# VBA substitute for Microsoft Office RT?

Tags: microsoft-office, vba, vb.net

I've been working on VBA-based applications for automating Excel and other MS Office applications. Now I'd like to expand to MS Office RT, but I've read that Office RT has no VBA support. Is there any substitute for VBA that allows Office automation with Office RT? In particular, is it possible to automate Office RT through VB.NET?

Note: I can't check this out on my own because I don't have a copy of Office RT yet, and I don't want to buy a copy of it until I know whether it supports automation or not.

Comment: It doesn't support VBA. If you write other languages that call the applications, well, that would be an entirely different beast.

Comment: @Raystafarian: Even if it's totally different from VBA, that would be fine, as long as it allows some form of automation of Office RT.

Comment: I think that depends more on the OS and hardware as to what you can program.